# Programmatic creation of JSF components with EL expressions using EL functions throws javax.el.ELException: function not found

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I'm programmatically creating the PrimeFaces `<p:column>`s for a `<p:dataTable>` using a so-called `BaseColumnHandler`. There's one column here that shows an icon or not, depending on some condition given by the row's entity (here 'event').

In JSF this would look something like this (inside a `<p:dataTable ... var="event" ...>`):

```
<p:column ...>
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/somePath/to/icon/whatever.png"
                    title="#{of:format1('{0} conflicts available', event.results.size())}"
                    style="#{event.whatEverVisibleCondition ? '' : 'visibility: hidden;'}"
                    ... />
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/somePath/to/icon/whatsoever.png"
                    title="What so ever available"
                    style="#{event.whatSoEverVisibleCondition ? '' : 'visibility: hidden;'}"
                    ... />

</p:column>
```

This simply shows a single info column where each row (event entity) displays an icon for an available feature or not (CSS `visibility: hidden;` replaces the JSF `rendered` attribute, because we need the icon space to be used in case of invisiblity so that icons will align).

Please assume the icon paths to be correct.

In the class building the icon column, I have the following lines:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyColumnHandler
{
    // get necessary instances to handle value expressions
    FacesContext      facesContext     = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext         elContext        = facesContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory factory          = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();

    @PostConstruct
    public void buildColumns()
    {
        ...

        UIGraphic graphicImage = new GraphicImage();
        this.setTitleExpressionToComponent(graphicImage, "#{of:format1('{0} conflicts available', event.results.size())}");

        ...
    }

    private void setTitleExpressionToComponent(UIComponent component, String expression)
    {
        // expression goes to "title" attribute and is of type String
        component.setValueExpression("title", this.factory.createValueExpression(this.elContext, expression, String.class));
    }

    ...
}
```

When I render the page however, I get something like this:

```
javax.el.ELException: Function 'of:format1' not found
    at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:172)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.prepare(ExpressionBuilder.java:219)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:230)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:273)
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.createValueExpression(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldExpressionFactory.createValueExpression(WeldExpressionFactory.java:50)
    at com.company.ci.common.view.framework.columnhandling.MyColumnHandler.setTitleExpressionToComponent(MyColumnHandler.java:121)
```

Obviously, the EL cannot find the OmniFaces function `format1`.

I have however added `xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"` to every file that I can think of that is being used on the page that causes the exception.

**Q**:

What do I have to do to make the OmniFaces `of:format1` function available, so that the exception isn't thrown? (hopefully a solution that doesn't require me to replace some ELContext with a custom class... if possible at all)

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear from the question when exactly this code runs. It's also confusing to see a "component handler" being registered as a managed bean instead of a `TagHandler` or `ComponentHandler`. It's also scary to see a request scoped variable like `FacesContext` being assigned as a view scoped bean property. A true [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot. At least, when I run `createValueExpression()` during `<f:event type="postAddToView">` via a managed bean "the usual way", then it works just fine for me with Mojarra 2.2.8. Which JSF impl/version are you using?

Comment: That said, are you absolutely positive that you need to do it in Java side and not in XHTML side? There's **nothing** which can only be done in Java side and not in XHTML side. Declaring and creating components in XHTML side is much more clean and declarative than in Java side.

Comment: By the way, to exclude specifically OmniFaces functions, does it work if you use another EL functions library, such as JSTL `fn:xxx()`?

Comment: Actually, the code runs from a page that uses the column handler for Criteria query generation: the columns configured in the app define its joins and conditions etc. That said, I **am** absolutely sure that I must create the PF columns programmatically. However, I cannot 100% tell which XHTML I need to include the `xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"` to that *could* fix my problem. It is pure desparation to go all the way down to the `ELContext` programmatically. I'm using Mojarra 2.1.22. I will try other functions, thanks for the tip.

Comment: BTW: the code display, that is the view-scoped bean, the naming and all this what doesn't make 110% sense is not quite the true story. It's all far better designed in real life, just assume all the JSF/CDI stuff is OK... it's just that I cannot tell why the function isn't found, as I said, it's actually triggered from a page that shows a statistic (# of entities applying to a filter on an overview dashboard). I have included `xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"` anywhere I can think of that this page is `<ui:include>`ing.

Comment: Strange. On the dashboard page, that previously threw the `ELException` there none now, however, now on the page where the actual `<p:column>` is rendered with the expression `"#{fn:length(event.results)}"` an `ELException` is now thrown: fn:length not found.

Comment: OK, not OmniFaces functions related, just EL functions in general. As to the approach, if you intend to control the building of the view, rather use view build time tags from JSTL in XHTML side instead of Java flow control statements in Java side.